# What are risks / expenses to buy a house in Germany?

Tags: taxes, germany, expenses, estate-planning, house

I think about buying a house in Germany (Frankfurt).
How can I learn full list of expenses I should pay next at least ~15 years?
My friend scares me that there are always hidden problems like central street-pipes replacing for many thousand euros.
How to know the truth?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As a first step I would talk to a German real estate agent (Immobilienmakler), who will be able to give you an idea of the costs, fees, insurance needed to purchase a property, and who would be able to address your other common concerns.  If you are clear in your initial phone call about what your resources, desires and intentions are; you will probably be able to find an agent (even if you have to call a few different offices first) who will be happy to educate you and give you a ballpark figure for common costs.

Another source you might try is looking on German social networks (facebook, reddit, etc) for other young people in the region who have recently gone through the home buying process, and who would be willing to describe their experience to you.  I've found that many people are happy to respond to social media posts such as "I am a 28 year old looking to buy a house, what should I expect?"

Comment: Sounds like good advice; however, on the assumption that "_central street-pipes replacing_" is an example of an infrequent, but to-be-expected (if you know about it) cost, then you probably don't want people "_who have recently gone through the home buying process_" as they may not yet have encountered such things... you probably want to target people who have had a house for 5+ years.

Comment: Central street pipes replacement is more of a once in a few decades event. If you buy used, best ask the seller when the street was overhauled last. If you build on an existing street, ask the neighbors. If you build on a new street, ask the city about Erschließungskosten, add those to your buying costs and then don't worry about it for the next three decades.

Comment: @TripeHound I would consider social media sources to be a secondary source, useful to getting information from the perspective of a new buyer.  Issues such as "central street-pipes replacing", on the other hand, are issues with which a good real estate agent should be more familiar.